# How to output results in a specific format？

Tags: output-formatting

i get some results using `Table`,codes are as this

```
nu = 8.163265306122447`;
Table[FindRoot[(I*m[k])*Tanh[I*m[k]] - nu, {m[k], k*\[Pi], 
   k*\[Pi] - \[Pi]/2, k*\[Pi] + \[Pi]/2}], {k, 1, 10}]
```

and it outputs

```
{{m[1] -> 1.78621}, {m[2] -> 5.28713}, {m[3] -> 8.66944}, {m[4] -> 
   11.9678}, {m[5] -> 15.2155}, {m[6] -> 18.4326}, {m[7] -> 
   21.6303}, {m[8] -> 24.8149}, {m[9] -> 27.9906}, {m[10] -> 31.1597}}
```

i just wan to output the results in this form and in one cell

```
m[1]=1.78621;
m[2]=5.28713;
m[3]=8.66944;
...
```

so how to deal with it? iam sorry i have no trying codes as i don't konw how to try.

```
nu = 8.163265306122447`;
s1 = Table[
  FindRoot[(I*m[k])*Tanh[I*m[k]] - nu, {m[k], k*\[Pi], 
    k*\[Pi] - \[Pi]/2, k*\[Pi] + \[Pi]/2}], {k, 1, 10}]

s2 = s1 /. {"->" -> "="}
```

however it doesn't work

Comment: You're on the wrong way. Please press F1 and read the document of `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) carefully. `ReplaceAll` is a function you can't circumvent as long as you're using _Mathematica_.

Comment: i don't konw how to `repalceall` about the `[`,`->` and some specific characters

Comment: Now read the document of `Rule` and `Equal`, and read this Chinese tutorial: https://note.youdao.com/ynoteshare1/index.html?id=c5114ccda3270199fd801952cf785bff&type=note especially the 函数和它的马甲 section.

Comment: `nu = 8.163265306122447\`;
Table[FindRoot[(I*m[k])*Tanh[I*m[k]] - nu, {m[k], k*\[Pi], 
      k*\[Pi] - \[Pi]/2, k*\[Pi] + \[Pi]/2}][[1]], {k, 1, 10}] /. 
  Rule :> Equal // Column`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon,it seems that i want to use `=`and delete `[` and `]`

Comment: `Column[StringForm["\`1\`=\`2\`", #[[1]], NumberForm[#[[2]], 6]] & /@ 
  Table[FindRoot[(I*m[k])*Tanh[I*m[k]] - nu, {m[k], k*\[Pi], 
      k*\[Pi] - \[Pi]/2, k*\[Pi] + \[Pi]/2}][[1]], {k, 1, 10}]]`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon，it seems your answer has a Good effect,however i have to copy the result to `word` or `txt` forms,when i copy the result cell and paste,`█("m""[""1""]""="""1.78621""@"m""[""2""]""="""5.28713""@"m""[""3""]""="""8.66944""@"m""[""4""]""="""11.9678""@"m""[""5""]""="""15.2155""@"m""[""6""]""="""18.4326""@"m""[""7""]""="""21.6303""@"m""[""8""]""="""24.8149""@"m""[""9""]""="""27.9906""@"m""[""10""]""="""31.1597"")`,i just can't use it.

Comment: Select the output cell, use the menu command <Edit | Copy As | Plain Text>, paste into Word.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon，great and you solved my problem perfectly and <Edit | Copy As | Plain Text> is greatly effective!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code depends on what are you going to achieve. If your aim is simply to assign the values to m[i] the most straightforward way is the following. Let res be your result:

```
res = {{m[1] -> 1.78621}, {m[2] -> 5.28713}, {m[3] -> 
    8.66944}, {m[4] -> 11.9678}, {m[5] -> 15.2155}, {m[6] -> 
    18.4326}, {m[7] -> 21.6303}, {m[8] -> 24.8149}, {m[9] -> 
    27.9906}, {m[10] -> 31.1597}};
```

Let us first remove the internal curly braces:

```
res1 = Flatten[res, 1]

(*  {m[1] -> 1.78621, m[2] -> 5.28713, m[3] -> 8.66944, m[4] -> 11.9678, 
 m[5] -> 15.2155, m[6] -> 18.4326, m[7] -> 21.6303, m[8] -> 24.8149, 
 m[9] -> 27.9906, m[10] -> 31.1597}  *)
```

And now you easily get the value of any of your m-s. Say, for m[5] you should only evaluate

```
m[5] /. res1

(* 15.2155 *)
```

This construct you can substitute in any your code, where you need to substitute m[i].

You can also assign the values for all m[i] once forever:

```
MapAt[(Apply[Set, #] &), res1, All]

(*  {1.78621, 5.28713, 8.66944, 11.9678, 15.2155, 18.4326, 21.6303, \
24.8149, 27.9906, 31.1597}   *)
```

Now, let us check, say, the value of m[2]:

```
m[2]

(*  5.28713  *)
```

Finally, may it by that you only wish to represent them in a form that is convenient for a visual inspection? In that case do the following:

```
Column[MapAt[(Apply[Equal, #] &), res1, All]]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: it seems that i can't use your code,`res = {{m[1] -> 1.78621}, {m[2] -> 5.28713}, {m[3] -> 
     8.66944}, {m[4] -> 11.9678}, {m[5] -> 15.2155}, {m[6] -> 
     18.4326}, {m[7] -> 21.6303}, {m[8] -> 24.8149}, {m[9] -> 
     27.9906}, {m[10] -> 31.1597}};
res1 = Flatten[res, 1]
Column[MapAt[(Apply[Equal, #] &), res1, All]]` and it runs out `MapAt::psl: Position specification All in MapAt[Equal@@#1&,{m[1]->1.78621,m[2]->5.28713,m[3]->8.66944,m[4]->11.9678,m[5]->15.2155,m[6]->18.4326,m[7]->21.6303,m[8]->24.8149,m[9]->27.9906,m[10]->31.1597},All] is not an integer or a list of integers. >>`

Comment: and the most important is that when i cpoy this result cell to `MS word` or `txt` or `matlab`,the form changed and you can't use it.

Comment: That was my question from the very beginning. You should precisely specify what do you need this result for. It appears that I answered not to the question you had in mind. Where do you want to export it and for what purpose? What are you going to do with it in Word? Or in Editor? Sorry, I do not know matlab at all.

Comment: To address your claim that error message shows up. This code works for me (Mma 12, Win. 10). The reason that it made some problems for you may be that on your machine Mma "remembered" some of the used values. Try to apply Clear to all variables used in this code.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for OP probably because OP is in _v7_, which should have been mentioned in the body of the question.

Comment: @xzczd That is quite possible. However, from the discussion I got an impression that the OP did not clearly formulated his final goal. It seems now that it is about export, rather than representation in Mma. It is quite probable that the solution OP needs is completely different, nothing to do with what I offered. But I propose that OP first explains his aims more clearly.